# AHCI and write-caching

Tags: thinkpad, ahci, hard-drive-cache

In the readme for an update to the Intel Rapid Storage AHCI Driver from Lenovo, they suggest that to improve performance I should turn off Windows write-cache buffer flushing on my drives. http://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles/ggim05ww.txt

Why would Lenovo recommend making this change? Are there any drawbacks? This is for a W530 laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there is no inconvenience, is only a recommendation for obtain better performance.

Mark this option is recommended only for disks with a backup power supply.